# Complex Numbers and Hyperbolic Functions

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

How would you evaluate: $\mathfrak{R}\left[(1+i)\sin\left(\dfrac{(2+i)\pi}{4}\right)\right]$?

I know that $\cos x = \dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ and $\sin x = \dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$.

I have also tried expanding the $\sin\left(\dfrac{(2+i)\pi}{4}\right)$ part to $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{i\pi}{4}\right)+\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{i\pi}{4}\right)$ using the addition formula for $\sin$ angle.

Answer (score 1):

We know that
$$
\sin\left(\dfrac{(2+i)\pi}{4}\right)=\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\frac{i\pi}{4}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{i\pi}{4}\right),
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
(1+i)\sin\left(\dfrac{(2+i)\pi}{4}\right)&= (1+i)\cos\left(\frac{i\pi}{4}\right)\\
&=(1+i)\left(\dfrac{e^{i\frac{i\pi}{4}}+e^{-i\frac{i\pi}{4}}}{2}\right)\\
&=(1+i)\left(\dfrac{e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}+e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}}{2}\right)\\
&=\left(\dfrac{e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}+e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}}{2}\right)+i\left(\dfrac{e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}+e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}}{2}\right).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: so that makes it Re[(1+i)cos(pi/4)i]. HOw do i separate the imaginary term from the real term?

Comment: Use this $\cos x = \dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ and take $x=\dfrac{i\pi}{4}$.

Comment: yeah got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin\frac{(2+i)\pi}4=\sin\left(\frac\pi2+\frac\pi4i\right)=\cos\frac\pi4i$$

But

$$\cos\frac\pi4i=\frac12\left(e^{-\frac\pi4}+e^{\frac\pi4}\right)\implies$$

$$(1+i)\sin\frac{(2+i)\pi}4=\ldots$$

Comment: so that makes it Re[(1+i)cos(pi/4)i]. HOw do i separate the imaginary term from the real term?

Comment: Look at the value of $\;\cos\frac{\pi}4i=\cosh\frac\pi4\in\Bbb R\;$...!